# Postgres Index not working. Always executing Sequential Scan

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I have created index as below:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS employee_emp_id_index ON employee ((lower(emp_id))); --'emp_id' is of type : VARCHAR2

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM employee where lower(emp_id) = 'abc12345';
```

Execution plan:

```
Seq Scan on employee  (cost=0.00..2765.53 rows=16323 width=11) (actual time=0.071..13.247 rows=16340 loops=1)
Filter: (lower((emp_id)::text) = 'abc12345'::text)
Rows Removed by Filter: 11967
Buffers: shared hit=2341
Planning Time: 0.336 ms
Execution Time: 14.000 ms
```

Always executing sequential scan. Even if I turn off sequential scan, it is invoking Bitmap Heap Scan but not index scan.

Please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: Knowing that you did an EXPLAIN ANALYZE doesn't do any good if you won't show us the output of it.

Comment: If you have many similar values the database may resort to a sequential scan.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I was away for couple of days. I have edited my post per the feedback. I am new to the community and eager to learn and contribute here.

Comment: I think the problem here may be that I do not have enough records in the database. Total records = 28302 and records with employee id 'abc12345' = 16335. 
Please suggest.

Comment: Your query retrieves about 50% of the rows. A Seq Scan is the most efficient way to do that